# Mongoose multiple $push to multiple arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update more than one database entry in my Mongodb:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,
    {$push: {people_seen: person_id}},
    {$push: {people_liked: person_id}},
    function(err, usr){
        console.log(req.user);
        res.json({success: true});
});
```

However, only `people_seen` is getting saved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator multiple time. The second argument to [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) is an options document. The correct `$push`'s syntax is:

```
{ $push: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```

and the right query in your query is:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,
    { $push: { people_seen: person_id, people_liked: person_id }},
    function(err, usr){
        console.log(req.user);
        res.json({ success: true });
});
```